# I did not receive 20.87856619 Monero sent from Upbit to Monero-wallet-GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

lost my monero.

Sent to # 1 address(hyeok) but not received.

Tell me how to find it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

try remote node / 
no sync?

[image]
[image]

change height

[image]

Comment: Your daemon is erroneously reporting that it's fully synced. You can use that ^ guide to verify the sync status and for general assistance with your missing transaction.